# ImportError: cannot import name 'string_int_label_map_pb2' On windows

Tags: python, tensorflow, classification, object-detection, training-data

I am attempting to use the tensorflow object classifier and am having some slight issues when it comes to importing the models.

I am following a tutorial (https://gilberttanner.com/blog/installing-the-tensorflow-object-detection-api) and from what I seen on google alot of others have had similar issues regarding the import.

Having downloaded TensorFlow/models, pycocotools, I have then installed protobuf, I managed to run it and convert the PROTO files to Python Source file - I thought I was on the home stretch here.

But when running through the object_detector tutorial I get so far before I run into this importerror

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
`ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-962ae4a715f3> in <module>
      1 from object_detection.utils import ops as utils_ops
----> 2 from object_detection.utils import label_map_util
      3 from object_detection.utils import visualization_utils as vis_util
      4 from protos import string_int_label_map_pb2

c:\users\robert\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\object_detection\utils\label_map_util.py in <module>
     19 import tensorflow as tf
     20 from google.protobuf import text_format
---> 21 from object_detection.protos import string_int_label_map_pb2
     22 
     23 enter code here` 

ImportError: cannot import name 'string_int_label_map_pb2' from 'object_detection.protos' 

(c:\users\robert\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\object_detection\protos\__init__.py)
```

I am a bit confused here - Maybe I stared at this for a bit too long..-

I can go into the files and within object_detection/protos there is a string_int_label_map_pb2

So whats going wrong?

I have looked at alot of other posted similar to this but I cannot seem to find an exact answer for what I need. I have set the pythonpath, ran python setup.py build & install. But I am stuck.

I am still new to all this, and Im sure I am being really dense and missing something obvious. But any help would be amazing.

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried the fix in this issue? https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/1595

Comment: I followed these instruction from the link. But am still getting the same  import error as before. 

" I got a very easy solution
put this python file in object detection/protos folder:- https://github.com/datitran/object_detector_app/blob/master/object_detection/protos/string_int_label_map_pb2.py

It will solve your error

and switching the import from 'object_detection.protos' to just 'protos' 

In the Jupyter notebook I am also seeing 
----> 2 from object_detection.utils import label_map_util

Could an error with label_map_util be causing the issue with String_int_label_map?

Comment: I changed the from object_detection.utlis import to whats below. 

from object_detection.utils import ops as utils_ops
from utils import label_map_util
from object_detection.utils import visualization_utils as vis_util
from protos import string_int_label_map_pb2

This got me past that step, but now onto the next issue of not found error in label map stage.

Comment: When I run ---

# List of the strings that is used to add correct label for each box.
PATH_TO_LABELS = 'models/research/object_detection/data/mscoco_label_map.pbtxt'
category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index_from_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS, use_display_name=True)


Getting error--

NotFoundError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
Notfound error
----> 3 category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index_from_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS, use_display_name=True)